# How to pass environment variables from repository to Github action script

Tags: github, github-actions

We are writing a generic github action workflow which will be checked into multiple repositories. Currently, we have to write many `if` and `case` conditions to manage some custom logic for different repos. For example, if it is a Java based repo then run build step but if it is a python repo then skip that step.

Is it possible for each repo to set an environment variable to this action saying something like `JAVA-REPO=TRUE`. Action can behave accordingly then.

Something similar to passing commandline arguments or reading a properties file which resides in repo and can be read by action. This will reduce complexity in the action script by a great deal.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, you can set environment variables through your workflow and use them in your scripts.

For example, if you want to run a **python script** and use a env variable set on the action, you can do something like this in your workflow:

```
    steps:
      - name: Run script with env variable
        env:
          PYTHON-REPO: true
        run: python script.py
```

And in your **Python** script, you will be able to do:

```
import os

repo = os.environ.get("PYTHON-REPO")
```

To retrieve the value and then use it.

In **Java**, the logic would be the same in the workflow, but in the `.java` class you would have to use something like this:

```
Boolean repo = System.getenv("JAVA-REPO");
```